# peace lily is dying

Tags: diseases, peace-lily

I have 2 peace lily and I keep them inside, water them once a week but one of them started to drop and dying, I moved it to a bigger pot and it was getting well but then drop and die again!

[image]
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may require some sunlight. Put out side for few days and water it. Make sure that water is not logged in pot.

Comment: I will try that